# Intersection of straight line and circle

Tags: tikz-pgf

Why does this example only partially work?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc,arrows,trees,positioning,through,intersections,fadings}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (6,0);
\coordinate (c) at (9,6);
\node(A)[label=$A$] at (a) {$\bullet$};
\node(B)[label=50:$B$] at (b)  {$\bullet$};
\node(C)[label=$C$] at (c) {$\bullet$};
\draw[thick] (a)--(b)--(c)--cycle;
%           \node(c1) at (a)[draw,circle through=(b)] {};
%           \coordinate(ac) at(intersection 1 of c1 and a--c);
%           
%           \node(c2) at (ac)[draw,circle through=(b)] {};
%           \node(c3) at (b)[draw,circle through=(ac)] {};
%           \coordinate(bta) at(intersection 1 of c2 and c3 );
%           \node(xx)[label=$C$] at (bta) {$\bullet$};
%       \coordinate(bisa) at(intersection 1 of a--bta and b--c);
%       \draw (a)--(bisa);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% work %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \node(c4) at (b)[draw,circle through=(a)] {};
            \coordinate(bc) at(intersection 1 of c4 and b--c);
            \node(xx)[label=$prova$] at (bc) {$\bullet$};
            \node(c5) at (bc)[draw,circle through=(a)] {};
            \node(c6) at (a)[draw,circle through=(bc)] {};
            \coordinate(btb) at(intersection 1 of c5 and c6 );
        \node(xx)[label=$prova$] at (btb) {$\bullet$};
        \coordinate(bisb) at(intersection 1 of b--btb and a--c);
        \draw (b)--(bisb);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% work %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% it doesn't work%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\node(c7) at (c)[draw,circle through=(b)] {};
\coordinate(ac) at(intersection 2 of c7 and a--c);
\node(xx)[label=$prova2$] at (ac) {$\bullet$};
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% it doesn't work %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi user13225, welcome to TeX.sx! I've formatted your code block for you, which can be done by selecting the block and pressing the `{}` button (or alternatively indenting each line by four spaces, but who wants to do that manually?). Could you add a bit more detail to your question?

Comment: Why there is one extra brace `}` after the `\end{document}`?

Comment: @HarishKumar: Sorry, I missed that when I formatted the code block. I believe it was an attempt by user13225 to format the code.

Comment: @Jake: Oh, I thought it was a mistake which might have troubled user13225. Thanks

Comment: You should always state what you try to achieve and what error or misbehavior you get instead.

Comment: @Jake: Please then always fix other minor issues as well. Here for example changing title and text to start capitalized.

Comment: @user13225 Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 17):

First I think it would be best to use the new syntax with `path name`, `name intersections` etc. like in the Euclide's tutorial with pgf 2.1.

`(c)--(a)` instead of `(a)--(c)` solves the problem.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc,arrows,through,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (6,0);
\coordinate (c) at (9,6);
\node(A)[label=$A$] at (a) {$\bullet$};
\node(B)[label=50:$B$] at (b)  {$\bullet$};
\node(C)[label=$C$] at (c) {$\bullet$};
\draw[thick] (a)--(b)--(c)--cycle;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% work %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            \node(c4) at (b) [draw,circle through=(a)] {};
            \coordinate(bc) at (intersection 1 of c4 and b--c);
            \node(xx) at (bc) {\color{red}$\bullet$};
            \node(c5) at (bc)[draw,circle through=(a)] {};
            \node(c6) at (a)[draw,circle through=(bc)] {};
            \coordinate(btb) at(intersection 1 of c5 and c6 );
            \node(xx) at (btb) {\color{green}$\bullet$};
            \node(bisb) at (intersection 1 of b--btb and a--c){\color{blue}$\bullet$};
            \draw[dashed] (b)--(bisb);     
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% work %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\node(c7) at (c)[draw,circle through=(b)] {};
\coordinate(ac) at (intersection 1 of c7 and c--a);
\node(xx) at (ac) {\color{orange}$\bullet$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

With a more recent syntax, the code becomes

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc,arrows,through,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
  \tikzset{mark coordinate/.style={inner sep=0pt,
                                   outer sep=0pt,
                                   minimum size=3pt,
                                   fill=#1,
                                   circle}
                                   }
  \draw[thick] (0,0)  coordinate [mark coordinate=black,label=$A$]      (a) --
               (6,0)  coordinate [mark coordinate=black,label=50:$B$]   (b) --
               (9,6)  coordinate [mark coordinate=black,label=$C$]      (c) -- cycle ; 

  \node [name path=Circle1,draw,circle through=(a)] at (b) {};
  \path [name path=BC] (b) -- (c); 
  \path [name intersections={of=BC and Circle1, name=i}] 
        (i-1) coordinate [mark coordinate=red];
  \node [name path=Circle2,draw,circle through=(a)]   at (i-1)   {};
  \node [name path=Circle3,draw,circle through=(i-1)] at (a)     {};
  \fill [name intersections={of=Circle2 and Circle3, name=j}] 
        (j-1) coordinate [mark coordinate=green];
  \path [name path=AC]   (a) -- (c);
  \path [name path=Bj-1] (b) -- (j-1);
  \fill [name intersections={of=Bj-1 and AC, name=k}] 
        (k-1) coordinate [mark coordinate=blue];
  \draw [red] (b)--(k-1);      
  \node [name path=Circle4,draw,circle through=(b)] at (c)  {};
  \fill [name intersections={of=Circle4 and AC, name=l}] 
        (l-1) coordinate [mark coordinate=orange];    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @MartinScharrer yes but I will try but my english is not good enough to add a lot of explanations.

Comment: This answer also begs for an example with `tkz-euclide` :)

Comment: @percusse Yes it's possible for sure !  I need to update `tkz- euclide` to be able to use `path name`but it's complicated because I use special tools to calculate the intersections.